# Can't get markdown to work on wordpress.com

Tags: markdown, wordpress.com

I switched to Wordpress as Blogger was mangling my markup (some bug spewing `<br>` everywhere).

Now I noticed Wordpress supports markdown, which is even better.

I enabled Markdown following the Wordpress support page.  Yet markdown formatting isn't working for me.  E.g. if I type `*foo*` in the HTML tab, I see "*foo*" in the Visual tab (and no italics).

Note that I had to go into "WP admin", below "Settings" in the menu, and *then* go to the "Settings" menu there, to enable markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Visual" tab doesn't expand Markdown to HTML.  Use the Preview button instead.